# telebot шалит в message.chat.id

Tags: python, telebot, chat

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def start(message):
    adm = [юзер айди]  # список из id пользователей
    if message.chat.id not in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не дозволено')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чего изволите сударь?')
```

мой id внесен в adm но бот пишет не дозволено
p.s Если писать в лс боту то работает, если использовать в чате то нет

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверяете ID чата, а не пользователя написавшего сообщение, а в список `adm` Вы занесли свой ID. Соответственно, при использовании бота в чате ID чата не совпадает с ID админа и ничего не работает. Используйте вместо `message.chat.id` это: `message.from_user.id`